# Can you please solve this problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q1: prove that if a|b and b|a, then a=b or a=-b?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

If $a|b$, $ak=b$ for some integer $k$. Similarly, $bl=a$ for some integer $l$.
Substituting the value of $a=bl $ in $ak=b$, we get $lk=1$, so what values can $l$ and $k$ take?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let $b=pa, a=qb=???$  How many ways can you factor $1$?